# How to stop android system from redeliver old intent to IntentService?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to cancel old intent and proceed with the latest intent

For example:

On my MainActivity:-

```
for(int i=0 ; i<10; i++){ 
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,MService.class);  
    intent.putExtra("text", i);
    mContext.startService(intent);
}
```

On my IntentService:-

```
public class MService extends IntentService{

private static final String TAG = "MService"; 

public MService () {
    super(TAG); 
    setIntentRedelivery(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate(); 
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand");
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG,"onHandleIntent");
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    String  value = (String)(bundle.get("text"));
    Log.d(TAG, "Received value---"+value);
    SystemClock.sleep(2000); 
    } 
}
```

And My Log Looks Like:

```
MService: onCreate
    MService: onStartCommand
    MService: onHandleIntent
    MService: onStartCommand
    MService: onStartCommand
    MService: onStartCommand
    MService: Received value---0
    MService: onStartCommand
    MService: onStartCommand
    MService: onStartCommand
    MService: onStartCommand
    MService: onStartCommand
    MService: onStartCommand
    MService: Received new location
    MService: onHandleIntent
    MService: Received value---1
    MService: onHandleIntent
    MService: Received value---2
    MService: onHandleIntent
    MService: Received value---3
    MService: onHandleIntent
    MService: Received value---4
    MService: onHandleIntent
    MService: Received value---5
    MService: onHandleIntent
    MService: Received value---6
    MService: onHandleIntent
    MService: Received value---7
    MService: onHandleIntent
    MService: Received value---8
    MService: onHandleIntent
    MService: Received value---9
```

I want to handle the last intent 9(latest) instead of handling 2 to 8

Comment: Please describe your problem in more details. What is your exact workflow? What method do you use to start that service? You can attach some code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) of the `IntentService`, it seems that as and when `startService(Intent)` is called (in your code, it is called in `for` loop), Android will create a new Worker thread. This worker thread then handles the `Intent`.

Please note that there is only one running `IntentService`, per <`service`> element in your manifest. If you call `startService()` 10 times, still, at most one `IntentService` will be running. Commands will queue up and be processed one at a time by `onHandleIntent`()

There is no API which `IntentService` class itself provides for cancellation of previous intent.

You will probably need to create your own version of `IntentService`, where you create your own `Service` subclass with its own work queue, one where you have the ability to cancel commands